# Can we add server name in log message?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, log4j, quartz-scheduler

I am using

> jboss at domain mode

and configured it to create a consolidate log file for all managed servers

Now I want server name in my log message is there any method i can try using simple java for it.

`I expect these results`

11:44:01,937 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) MyTaskOne start..

11:44:01,938 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Job run on server-one

11:44:01,937 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) MyTaskOne start..

11:44:01,938 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Job run on server-two

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
> <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
> <log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
>
>   <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
>      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout" >
>      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%c] (%x:%t) [User:%X{logguserid}] %m%n"/>
>      </layout>
>   </appender>
>
>   <appender name="AppLogWriter" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
>     <param name="File" value="D:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/domain/log/server.log"/>
>     <param name="Append" value="true"/>
>     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
>     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100"/>
>     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
>       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%x:%t) [User:%X{logguserid}] %m%n"/>
>     </layout>
>   </appender>  
>   
>   <appender name="AuditLogWriter" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
>     <param name="File" value="D:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/domain/log/server.log"/><!--path of auditlog file-->
>     <param name="Append" value="true"/>
>     <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
>     <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
>     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
>       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%x:%t) [User:%X{logguserid}] %m%n"/>
>     </layout>
>   </appender>
>
>   <root>
>     <priority value="info"/>
>     <appender-ref ref="AppLogWriter"/>
>     <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
>   </root>
>
> <logger name=".audit.log" level="info" additivity="false">
>    <appender-ref ref="AuditLogWriter" />
> </logger>
>
>
> <appender name="CLASSLOADING" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">     
>   <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>     
>   <param name="File" value= "D:/Logs/classloading.log"/>     
>   <param name="Append" value="false"/>    
>   <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>    
>   <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>     
>   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">    
>     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %m%n"/>    
>   </layout> 
> </appender>   
>
> <category name="org.jboss.classloading">
>   <priority value="TRACE"/>    
>   <appender-ref ref="CLASSLOADING"/> 
> </category>
>
> </log4j:configuration>
> ```

## Output

```
11:44:01,427 INFO  [com.Quartz_Oracle_11g.task.MyTaskOne] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) this is a info message
11:44:01,428 WARN  [com.Quartz_Oracle_11g.task.MyTaskOne] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) this is a warn message
11:44:01,429 ERROR [com.Quartz_Oracle_11g.task.MyTaskOne] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) this is a error message
11:44:01,431 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) MyTaskOne done..

11:44:01,728 INFO  [org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Duplicate step [stepOne] detected in execution of job=[demoJob]. If either step fails, both will be executed again on restart.
11:44:01,862 INFO  [org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Executing step: [stepOne]
11:44:01,937 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) MyTaskOne start..

11:44:01,938 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Job

11:44:01,938 INFO  [com.Quartz_Oracle_11g.task.MyTaskOne] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) this is a info message
11:44:01,939 WARN  [com.Quartz_Oracle_11g.task.MyTaskOne] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) this is a warn message
11:44:01,940 ERROR [com.Quartz_Oracle_11g.task.MyTaskOne] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) this is a error message
11:44:01,941 INFO  [stdout] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) MyTaskOne done..

11:44:02,151 INFO  [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Job: [SimpleJob: [name=demoJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{JobID=1573539240754}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
11:44:02,153 INFO  [org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin] (schedulerFactoryBean_Worker-1) Trigger [DEFAULT.jobTrigger] completed firing job [DEFAULT.demoJob] with resulting trigger instruction code: DO NOTHING. Next scheduled at:  12-11-2019 11:45:00.000
```

Comment: what does your current logs look like and what is your current log4j configuration?

Comment: @funkyjelly here is my log4j config and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it to Log4j Mapped Diagnostic Context:

```
MDC.put("jboss.server.name", System.getProperty("jboss.server.name"));
```

Than you can add it to the Log4j conversion pattern:

```
"... [jboss-server-name=%X{jboss.server.name}] ..."
```